# Security of keys while keeping my code clean

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I'm using a Google Cloud function to call a 3rd party API in my application.  The API key/secret will depend on the user in my application.

I would like to send a request from the cloud function to my application using a Bearer token and unique identifier to grab the key and secret on my side before sending it to the cloud function where the API request is made.  If either of these are incorrect, an error will be thrown.  If the call from Google Cloud to my app is made over https, is this a secure method of retrieving the key and secret?

Alternatively, I can just use environment variables within my cloud function, but I'd prefer to keep that function as clean as possible.

Comment: Functions are supposed to be small, fast and light-weight. You are adding a lot of complexity and execution time fetching data nd waiting for responses. I would encrypt the secret using the Function's attached service account public key and embed in my software. Then decrypt inside the function using the attached service account private key. Security and secrets are complex to manage. My suggestion depends on who I am protecting the secret from and the costs if compromised.